# violin_plot() with continuous axis for grouping variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The grouping variable for creating a `geom_violin()` plot in `ggplot2` is expected to be discrete for obvious reasons. However my discrete values are numbers, and I would like to show them on a continuous scale so that I can overlay a continuous function of those numbers on top of the violins. Toy example:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(x = sample(c(1,2,5), size = 1000, replace = T),
             y = rnorm(1000, mean = x))
ggplot(df) + geom_violin(aes(x=factor(x), y=y))
```

This works as you'd imagine: violins with their x axis values (equally spaced) labelled 1, 2, and 5, with their means at y=1,2,5 respectively. I want to overlay a continuous function such as y=x, passing through the means. Is that possible? Adding `+ scale_x_continuous()` predictably gives `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`. A solution would presumably spread the violins horizontally by the numeric x values, i.e. three times the spacing between 2 and 5 as between 1 and 2, but that is not the *only* thing I'm trying to achieve - overlaying a continuous function is the key issue.
If this isn't possible, alternative visualisation suggestions are welcome. I know I could replace violins with a simple scatter plot to give a rough sense of density as a function of y for a given x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. As you already guessed, spreading the violins by numeric values is the key to the solution. To this end I expand the df to include all x values in the interval `min(x)` to `max(x)` and use `scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)` so that all values are displayed.

Note: Thanks @ChrisW for the more general example of my approach.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42) 

df <- tibble(x = sample(c(1,2,5), size = 1000, replace = T), y = rnorm(1000, mean = x^2))
# y = x^2  
# add missing x values 
x.range <- seq(from=min(df$x), to=max(df$x)) 
df <- df %>% right_join(tibble(x = x.range))
#> Joining, by = "x"
# Whatever the desired continuous function is: 
df.fit <- tibble(x = x.range, y=x^2) %>% 
  mutate(x = factor(x))

ggplot() + 
  geom_violin(data=df, aes(x = factor(x, levels = 1:5), y=y)) + 
  geom_line(data=df.fit, aes(x, y, group=1), color = "red") + 
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing non-finite values (stat_ydensity).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Perfect, thanks! For reference for others, an example where `df_mean` above is replaced by an arbitrary theoretical fit instead of something direct from the data:

Comment: `library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)
df <- tibble(x = sample(c(1,2,5), size = 1000, replace = T),
             y = rnorm(1000, mean = x^2)) # y = x^2

# add missing x values
x.range <- seq(from=min(df$x), to=max(df$x))
df <- df %>%
  right_join(tibble(x = x.range))

# Whatever the desired continuous function is:
df.fit <- tibble(x = x.range, y=x^2) %>%
  mutate(x = factor(x))

ggplot() + 
    geom_violin(data=df, aes(x = factor(x, levels = 1:5), y=y)) + 
    geom_line(data=df.fit, aes(x, y, group=1), color = "red") +
    scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)`

Comment: Hmm @stefan maybe you can edit that into your answer so it formats properly?

Comment: Hi @ChrisW. Great idea. I replaced my example with your general example. Next time: Feel free to make the edit yourself. (;

Answer (score 3):

The functionality to plot violin plots on a continuous scale is directly built into `ggplot`.

The key is to keep the original continuous variable (instead of transforming it into a factor variable) and specify how to group it within the aesthetic mapping of the `geom_violin()` object. The width of the groups can be modified with the `cut_width` argument, depending on the data at hand.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = sample(c(1,2,5), size = 1000, replace = T),
             y = rnorm(1000, mean = x))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_violin(aes(group = cut_width(x, 1)), scale = "width") +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm')
```

[image: Minimal working example]

By using this approach, all geoms for continuous data and their varying functionalities can be combined with the violin plots, e.g. we could easily replace the line with a loess curve and add a scatter plot of the points.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_violin(aes(group = cut_width(x, 1)), scale = "width") +
  geom_smooth(method = 'loess') +
  geom_point()
```

[image: Extended working example]

More examples can be found in the `ggplot` helpfile for [violin plots](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_violin.html).